Understanding roots of unity in quadratic fields
Suppose we have a quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(z)$ with $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ and $z^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. How would one go about determining the possible $n^{\text{th}}$roots of unity for such a field?
I know that for $G=Aut(K[\zeta]/K)$, it must hold that $G\cong (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}=\{i+n\mathbb{Z}|gcd(i,n)=1\}$ and $|G|| \phi(n)$ (where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function).
I'm a bit lost on how to proceed from here. For example, how do I check if it is possible for $Q(z)$ to contain a fourth root of unity?

maybe start by asking which $n$ can have a root of unity being in an quadratic field. $n=3, 4$.  Then for n=3, you have to be a root of $x^2+x+1$, and for $n=4$ a root of $x^2+1$, and then plug in $x=a+bz$ for $a, b$

In your OP, you state $G\cong(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $|G|\ |\ \phi(n)$ as though they are two separate facts. Maybe it would be useful to note that in fact the prior statement is sufficient in telling us that $|G|=\phi(n)$?

Speaking generally, a number field $K$ contains a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity $\zeta_n$ iff it contains $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ as a subfield. Since $\zeta_n$ has minimal polynomial the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$, which has degree $\varphi(n)$, we know that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ has degree $\varphi(n)$ as a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ (this doesn't require a calculation of the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ which is a bit trickier). It follows that in order for this to be possible a necessary condition is that (by the tower law)
$$\varphi(n) \mid [K : \mathbb{Q}].$$
If $K$ is further assumed to be quadratic this gives $\varphi(n) \mid 2$, which is very restrictive. The only possibilities (excluding the degenerate cases $n = 1, 2$) are $n = 3, 4, 6$, where $\varphi(n) = 2$, and so we must have $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ exactly. Can you finish from here?
